# Query results in Oracle SQL Developer are different to those using .Net ODP

Tags: oracle, odp.net

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    case 
       when 
           AddressType IN (select code.codeid from code where code.codeset = AddressTypeCodeSet and code.description like 'Postal%') 
       then 'PostalAddress' 

       when 
           AddressType IN (select code.codeid from code where code.codeset = AddressTypeCodeSet and code.description like 'Email%') 
       then 
            'EmailAddress' 
       else 
            'OtherAddress' 
    end as AddressType

FROM VW_Address

WHERE AddressId=190000;
```

When I execute this query using SQL Developer, the result returned is `OtherAddress`. This is what I'm expecting. However, when I execute the same query via this code:

```
Dim cmd =
    New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand(["SQL HERE]")

cmd.Parameters.Add(":p0", OracleDbType.Int32)
cmd.Parameters(0).Value = 190000

cmd.BindByName = True

Dim r = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

I get a different result: `EmailAddress`

ODP is version `2.111.7.20`, Oracle is `11g`.

Comment: try to localize the problem. Remove the three bind variable commans and use 1:1 your query from above. What do you get?

Comment: Additionaly rewrite your query and use a outer join of the tables instead of two subqueries. In case that most of the adresses are emails, this may also perform better (one join instead of two subquery calls).

Comment: Do you have uncommitted changes in your SQL Developer session? If not perhaps show the table structures and relevant data for that ID.

Comment: Your  SQL does not contain the :0 bind variable. In case your real test case has multiple bind variables, be aware that by default ODP.NET binds by position, not by name.